# how to check in the html page, Intent Service get notification in java for Cordova 5.0 -Android 5.1 application

Tags: java, android, cordova

I am creating 'cordova-android chat application' in that 'GcmBroadcastReceiver.java' get the notification at that time write the message in the file. Also 'Chat.html' page design for chatting. I want to refresh this page only the notification comes. So how can I manage the html and java file?

Comment: Have you already tried something? What was the trouble with it?

Comment: I not try but i could not understand how to do it. plz can explain.

Comment: why don't you use 'signalr' to write a chat application?